# LocalDate.now() returns wrong date

Tags: java, spring-boot, localdate

I've written a REST Service using Spring Boot. The REST Service is running on a PaaS. I have an endpoint to create new items in a DB table. Every time a new item is created I assign it a created date by using:

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (" +
                "code, " +
                "description, " +
                "created_date)" +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                new Object[]{
                        code,
                        description,
                        currentDate.format(df)
                }
        );
```

The problem is that the `currentDate.format(df)` comes out as 17th of October 2017 while today is 24th of October 2017. The only connection I can see to the 17th of October is that it is the last time I restarted the `JAR` file on the PaaS. I've `SSH` into the environment where the service is running and run `date`. It returns `Tue Oct 24 17:54:23 UTC 2017`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you generate the date in the database (and use a proper date column instead of a varchar)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you are saying I guess your problem is that the currentDate is initialized at the start of your program and then you keep saving that same date, you probably have something like this

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
public void insert(String code, String description) {
  sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (" +
                "code, " +
                "description, " +
                "created_date)" +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                new Object[]{
                        code,
                        description,
                        currentDate.format(df)
                }
        );
}
```

You should move the instantiation of the date inside the method

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
public void insert(String code, String description) {
  LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
  sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (" +
                "code, " +
                "description, " +
                "created_date)" +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                new Object[]{
                        code,
                        description,
                        currentDate.format(df)
                }
        );
}
```

Comment: That is true. Thank you!

Comment: can you accept the answer if ti worked for you? thanks

Comment: sure just waiting for the "time out" to pass.